# resource IDs in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, resource-id

I define resource IDs as below:

    `#define _RESOURCE_ID             150
    #define IDR_OPBUTTON            _RESOURCE_ID + 10`

When I use below code to change the text of button, it doesn't work:

    `SetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDR_OPBUTTON, _T("-"));`

But if I give it a number directly, it does work:

    `#define IDR_OPBUTTON            160`

Can anybody tell me why? Thanks in advance!
Also, I tried function `GetDlgItemInt` for a textbox, it has the same behavior.

Comment: Did you try to put parenthesis? `#define IDR_OPBUTTON            (_RESOURCE_ID + 10)`

Comment: @sergiol, thanks! it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to put parenthesis?

```
#define IDR_OPBUTTON (_RESOURCE_ID + 10)
```